# Who is out after a run-out in Cricket?

Tags: rules, cricket

[image]
A is crossed the crease and B is crossed half of the pitch. Run-out happening in A's side.
Then who is out, A or B?

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, Batsman B is out - as they have not crossed on this run, his ground is where the wicket has been broken, and so he's out.

This is covered by Law 38.3:

The batsman out in the circumstances of 38.1 is the one whose ground is at the end where the wicket is put down.  See Laws 25.6 (Dismissal and conduct of a batsman and his/her runner) and 30.2 (Which is a batsman’s ground).

See https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws/run-out